# Record audio from a media player

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I record audio from my media player using c# winforms.

I'm trying to create an app that records audio from a player(vlc) and then saves it to my computer.

Any idea will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check this [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757161(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean using your media player? If you simply want to do it using C# just use the **winmm.dll** library.

1. Import the namespace.

   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
2. Declare the interop function

   [DllImport("winmm.dll",EntryPoint="mciSendStringA", ExactSpelling=true, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError=true)]
   private static extern int record(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);
3. Start recording

   record("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0);
      record("record recsound", "", 0, 0);
4. Stop recording and save to file

   record("save recsound d:\myRecordedAudioFile.wav", "", 0, 0);
      record("close recsound", "", 0, 0);

Comment: What I mean by media player is that, I'll like to record sound while playing sound from my media player.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NAudio](https://naudio.codeplex.com/), here is a quick sample

Two buttons Record and Stop,

```
public WaveIn _waveIn = null;
public WaveFileWriter fileToWrite = null;
private void btn_record_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _waveIn = new WaveIn();
    _waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1); 
    _waveIn.DataAvailable += _waveIn_DataAvailable; // event that keep listening mic
    fileToWrite = new WaveFileWriter(@"C:\Users\userName\Documents\myFile.wav", _waveIn.WaveFormat);
    _waveIn.StartRecording();
}

private void _waveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e) {
    if (fileToWrite != null) {
    fileToWrite.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded); // writes bytes to the wav file
    fileToWrite.Flush();
    }
}
private void btn_stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _waveIn.StopRecording();
}
```

Hope helps,

Comment: I'll give it a try